# React Final Form: onChange function for entire form?

Tags: reactjs, react-final-form

I'd like to preserve the form data user entered to some global state management, so that when user accidently closed the form, user can reopen the form and continue the job.

But I failed to find a way to do this with react-final-form.

What I want is something like:

```js
<Form onChange={(formdata) => saveToLocalStorage(formdata)}>
```

or

```js
useEffect(
  () => saveToLocalStorage(formdata),
  [formdata]
)
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

you can use FormSpy inside your form like this:

```
<FormSpy subscription={{values: true}} onChange={() => console.log('do smth')} />
```